# Beginner Using Tab Bar and SelectedIndex?

Tags: ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex

I've built an app 100% in IB without coding. I have little coding background, so please be kind with an answer. :)

I need a way to have a button (that is outside of my tab bar controller) take me to a specific tab in my tab bar controller. When I just do a modal link in IB, it will take me there, but the tab bar controller at the bottom is gone.

How exactly do I do this?
(Specifics with an example would be hugely appreciated)

Answer below:

I figured it out on my own...for those that may be looking for a similar solution...

All I did was create a global variable in my initial view controller called globalVariable.

```
//myview.h
#ifndef Globals_h
#define Globals_h

extern NSInteger globalVariable;

#endif
```

Populate that view with four buttons with a modal push to my tab bar controller. Each of those buttons has an action that changes the value of the globalVariable.

```
//myview.m
- (IBAction)button1Action:(id)sender {
    globalVariable = 0;
}
- (IBAction)button2Action:(id)sender {
    globalVariable = 1;
}
//etc etc
```

Then within the tab bar controller, just set your selectedIndex to the globalVariable within the viewDidLoad

```
//tabbarcontroller.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.selectedIndex = globalVariable;
}
```

Comment: Please summarize your article so we know exactly what your question/questions are. You could add the question in bold at the top or the bottom of the writting. Thanks!

Comment: Okay... I need to use a button to go to a specific tab in my tab bar controller. I'm trying to achieve this through IB since my entire app was written in this. How is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this without writing code. But from your question, I'm really not sure what you want to do. I'd suggest editing it (heavily) to just what you want to do, what you've tried, and what is wrong with it. Save the life story for your blog :)

Comment: Awesome that you posted your answer! However it would be much more helpful if you removed your solution from your question and wrote it as an answer to this question instead and then accepted that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own...for those that may be looking for a similar solution...

All I did was create a global variable in my initial view controller called globalVariable.

```
//myview.h
#ifndef Globals_h
#define Globals_h

extern NSInteger globalVariable;

#endif
```

Populate that view with four buttons with a modal push to my tab bar controller. Each of those buttons has an action that changes the value of the globalVariable.

```
//myview.m
- (IBAction)button1Action:(id)sender {
    globalVariable = 0;
}
- (IBAction)button2Action:(id)sender {
    globalVariable = 1;
}
//etc etc
```

Then within the tab bar controller, just set your selectedIndex to the globalVariable within the viewDidLoad

```
//tabbarcontroller.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.selectedIndex = globalVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get IB to set up a touch up action for your button

in that method  you want access to the tabbar controller which is the parent to your current controller

```
UITabBarController tbc = (UITabBarController) [self parentviewcontroller];
tbc.selectedIndex = 2;  //or whatever the index you need
```